# Installing Ubuntu on Macbook pro intel (2016) failed, GRUB recovery not available

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, macbook, usb-installation

I tried to install ubuntu on my old macbookpro (2016). The first bit of flashing the .iso file onto a usb using BalenaEtcher was fine. I managed to open the EFI Boot. Note: I used Disk Utility to erase the contents of my Mac hardisk before hand.

HOWEVER, the installation looked completely different than what youtube videos show, **it was a black screen and I had to choose the options via up and down arrow keys and enter.** I still managed to go through the process this way, and I installed it on the entire disk (not partitioned). At the end, it said install complete, but didn't offer a reboot option. I switched the computer off and on and **it was still a black screen** (see picture), [when it asked for my login details and password, I typed them in but it said login incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMoKn.jpg).

So I tried to follow instructions on resetting the password on GRUB, I managed to open GRUB but the GRUB doesn't give me a recovery mode option (see picture of grub) [I followed some youtube instructions to use `ls` in grub but can't find any hardisk with `root`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB1tO.jpg) .

Also my USB is no longer recognised and I can't even restart the mac to find the EFI boot option, to reinstall.

Please HELP? Did I completely mess up my computer? Is there anyway for me to save it?
I would appreciate suggestions of how I can:

1. Reset my login username/password
2. Redownload ubuntu and start over
3. Fix my USB stick so I can use it as normal or flash another install version on it.

Thank you so much in advance. As you can tell I'm very new to this and it is very intimidating.

Comment: do not know Mac. Looks like hd0,1 is ESP, 2 is / and 3 may be swap if not otherwise seen? From grub does this work? `configfile (hd0,1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg` or `set root=(hd0,2)` then `configfile /boot/grub/grub.cfg` There are two grub.cfg. The one in the ESP really just loads the one in / (root).  I thought I saw years ago best not to delete all of Mac system partitions. May be needed for repairs. Did you back up partitions you deleted. Or does Mac have a recovery type drive of some sort?

Comment: Try typing `normal` at that GRUB screen? Does the recovery mode option appear?

Comment: typing 'normal' takes me back to the black login screen that doesn't accept my password or username.

Comment: the 'configfile' didn't really do anything?
I think the Mac recovery mode was deleted since the install wiped the macOS... :/